# Got this while saving .tsx: ERROR in Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getFirstToken')

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

## Tooling

browser chrome version 117.0.5938.92 (Official Build) (32-bit)
SPFx version 1.18
Node.js version 18.18
spfx-fast-serve-helpers: 1.18.1

npm run serve works
gulp serve works

Problem arise when I save a .tsx file and I have this error message:

i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
× ｢wdm｣: Time: 205ms
Entrypoint sp-qms-doc-web-part = sp-qms-doc-web-part.js

**ERROR in Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getFirstToken')**
Occurred while linting C:\Local\Dev\SPFx\sp-qms-doc\src\webparts\spQmsDoc\components\Customizer.tsx:45
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
No issues found.

Immediatly after this I go on a .ts which export an interface, hit ctrl-s on this unchanged file and voila, it works.

Issue occured when I pulled an old branches which has a lot of conflicts. Conflicts were all fixed.

I've also installed a full .zip backup taken before the branch merge and even this version now has the same problem. It looks like is something global in my machine that is broken.